# Doesn't work ajax timeout and error in Internet Explorer 7,8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, timeout

This simple code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {  

var d = new Date();
$( "#new" ).click(function() {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "./work.php?_="+d.getTime(),  
  cache: false, 
  timeout: 20000,
  success:  function(msg){
   alert("Hello!");},
  error: function (data, status, e)
  {  
  if(status == "abort") alert("Cancel"); else
     if(status == "timeout") alert("TimeOut"); else
        alert("Error: "+status+" "+e);
  }
 });

});
});
</script>
<input type=button id=new />
</body>
</html>
```

And work.php:

```
<?php
sleep(14);
?>
```

In Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Intenet Explorer 9 output alert "Hello!" around 14 sec. In Internet Explorer 7,8 around 10 sec alert "Error: error Unknow".

Where is the mistake? How do I get a timeout was 20 seconds?

Comment: have you tried defining a `dataType`? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes. Data - d.getTime() for example against the cache internet explorer.